# Highcharts: How to make startRow and endRow work again when data is stored in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart that pulls data from a google spreadsheet. Since the last API update of Google I used googleSpreadsheetRange to get the data from source which works fine, except, the formerly used attributes startRow and endRow are completely ignored now.

```
startRow: 32,
endRow: 35,
```

I even tried to tell the API itself to skip the rows like this:

```
googleSpreadsheetRange: ["Gesamt!A1:C1", "Gesamt!A32:C35"],
```

But it doesn't work. I need the first row as a head row to make the chart understand the data. Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/loeneberga/bynLkjwe/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `complete` or `parsed` callbacks to parse your data after fetching it, but before the chart will be initialized to choose the range that you want to display.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8j0qf4vg/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.complete

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.parsed